# Using remote: true in Rails is working in Chrome, but not in Safari - seems to be an issue in calling the success function from the js.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested form (using nested_form gem) on which I am calling remote: true.

```
= nested_form_for @shopping_list, :remote => true, :html => {:class => "shopping-list-    form"} do |f|
```

I have it linked to the create action in the controller and the success function is returning the following from the create.js.erb file:

```
closeShoppingListForm();
$("#submit-success").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
$("#submit-success").delay(2000).fadeOut(500);

$.getScript(this.href);
return false;
```

Everything is working smoothly in Chrome - haven't tested Firefox yet. This issue has been hit with Safari before, but last time it was a function that was missing a closing ";" -- wasn't an issue with getting the success function from a js.erb file.

This is the code from the js file for the page for the closeShoppingListForm function -- it does exactly as it sounds - closes a bunch of things:

```
function closeShoppingListForm() {
  $("#shopping-list-form").hide();
  $("#running-total").hide();
  $("#total").hide();
  $("#create-shopping-list").fadeIn(500);
  $(".icon-remove").trigger("click");
  $("#shopping_list_name").val('');
  $("#total").html('');
 inventoryItemsQuantities = new Array();
};
```

Been googling and looking on SO for awhile - but now is time to submit it and see if anyone else has bumped into this. Any help at all is most welcome - thank you very much for taking a look.

Let me know if any other code snippets are needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any errors showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix… we looked at it awhile and it was just me going too quickly and throwing "return false" after the .getScript…

Perhaps this will help someone else not make that same mistake.

```
closeShoppingListForm();
$("#submit-success").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
$("#submit-success").delay(2000).fadeOut(500);

$.getScript(this.href);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the 'return false' in the code.  That way, it'll show the viewers the actual issue which will be more helpful.

Comment: Hi jschorr - it is there in the question. Right after $.getScript(this.href); - it's the next line. I'll post the code without that in the answer to clarify the difference.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed that!